# Find minimal element at runtime.

Tags: algorithm, temporary

Suppose I have a loop with a process inside in my program that calculates some value, and I want to retain the minimal value produced by that process. The most crucial issue is values are calculated sequentially and I do not know all of them in advance.

My solution is the following (pseudocode):

```
firstTime = true
minValue, currentValue

while ( not end )
    currentValue = valueFromProcess
    if ( (currentValue <= minValue) or firstTime )
        minValue = currentValue
        firstTime = false

return minValue
```

What is your solution or advises to mine? C/C++, Python are preferable but do not restrict yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a better solution than yours.

Only thing you could get rid of is the `firstTime` variable, when you set initial value of minValue to a huge number.

In Java:

```
int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
while (!end) {
    int currentValue = valueFromProcess();
    minValue = Math.min(minValue, currentValue);
}
return minValue;
```

Comment: OK. Thank you for your answer. But I feel that using of ``MAX_VALUE`` is kind of design flaw.

Comment: Everyone is entitled to their own opinion.